# Notepad++ file upload error (upload of X Failed)

Tags: html, timeout, editor, notepad++

Notepad++ has been giving me issues whenever I leave it for several minutes, seems to be going into some type of standby mode.

Whenever I go to save a file (connected to an FTP server via NppFTP), I get the errors below after the upload hangs for around 20 seconds.  If I try again immediately after I see the error message, the transfer then goes through.

--
Failure retrieving contents of directory /public_html/etc

-OR-

### Upload of C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config\NppFTP\Cache\filenameanddirectoryhere failed

Is there a way to prevent this? (get Notepad to ping the server every X seconds to prevent the connection timing out or something like that?)

Answer (score 0):

you got the server and give command setenforce 0 . this is a command to turn off se linux.